# AWS Translate: Get DetectedLanguageCode from DetectedLanguageLowConfidenceException

Tags: amazon-web-services, exception, .net-core, translate

I'm playing around with AWS Translate a bit. I want AWS Translate to auto-detect the source language, when I send a TranslateTextAsync request. Apparently, there can be a DetectedLanguageLowConfidenceException, which I want to handle by getting the DetectedLanguageCode from the exception and retry the translation. I was not able to get this exception to occur, so I don't know the structure of that response exception.

For the Java SDK, I found that there is a "getDetectedLanguageCode" function, but this one doesn't exist in the .NET SDK. I'm using AWSSDK.Translate v3.3.101.12.

How do I get the language code from the DetectedLanguageLowConfidenceException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted AWS Support and they reached out to their AWS Translate team. They write that

> C#/.Net does not support member variables in exceptions the way Java does. However, supplementary information about exceptions is stored in the Data dictionary of the exception

They also mention that AWS Translate will usually use even a low confidence guess before throwing a DetectedLanguageLowConfidenceException, so it seems like we don't really have to worry about it.

I still went and implemented the exception handling and have the following code to extract the detected language code data. This code is untested though:

```
catch (DetectedLanguageLowConfidenceException ex)
{
    var dictionary = ex.Data as Dictionary<object, object>;
    var detectedLanguageCode = dictionary?["DetectedLanguageCode"] as string;

    // Retry here with the detected low confidence language code.
}
```